# How to test if a result is statistically significant?

Tags: statistical-significance

I am trying to determine if a certain conversion on my site is statistically significant.  I remembered doing this type of stuff in school but I can't seem to remember how to do it now.

For 1st set: n = 7297 and conversion was 2.618%
For 2nd set: n = 6107 and conversion was 2.669%

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: With large enough samples, even trivial differences may be statistically significant. Is a difference in the third significant figure of any *practical* importance (how much difference could it make to you, really)? If there's no practical difference, there's no point testing for statistical significance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Percents are a proportion. The traditional way to test differences between proportions is the chi-square test. Based on the information you have given me (7106 and 191 [2.62%] in one half and 5944 and 163 [2.67%] in the other), the chi-square test results in a non-significant value of .88 (p value). Your proportions are 2.67 and 2.62, so it is no surprise that these are not statistically significant, despite your large sample.